# Integrated Authentication vs?

Tags: sql-server, authentication

my coworker and I had a debate and I am looking for Reddit to resolve it! We have PHP web apps running on IIS and are looking to setup the security to the database using one approach:

-What would you call the method where the service account running the application pool authentication to the SQL Server database using its own credentials?

-What would you call the method where the users connecting to the app on the network authenticate to the apps SQL Server database using their own network credentials?

Which is “integrated authentication”?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both "Integrated Authentication", as opposed to "SQL Authentication" which uses a user name and password stored in SQL Server.

The first is "Integrated Authentication With a Shared Servcie Account".

The second one "Integrated Authentication With a End-User Impersonation".